# If $g^{p^n}\pmod{p}=1$, with $p$ prime then is $g$ a primitive root mod $p$? How about the converse?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, cryptography

> Assume $g^{p^n}\pmod{p}=1$, with $p$ prime.
>
> 1. Is $g$ a primitive root mod $p$? If not why?
> 2. How about the converse? If not why?

This is not a homework question.

My attempt:

**Update - Corrections to my attempts 1 & 2**

1. Since $g^{p^n}\pmod{p}=1$, then order of $g | p^n$.
2. Assume $g$ a primitive root mod $p$, then there is no exponent $a$ s.t $g^a \pmod{p} =1$. By definition this is an element of order $p−1$.

Comment: It isn't.${}{}$

Comment: @lordshartheunknown why not?

Comment: Note that $1^{p^n}\equiv 1 \pmod p$.

Comment: Ok so that is a counter-example for g=1. Have I misunderstood what an element of prime power order is?

Comment: I'd say that you have.  A primitive root $\pmod p$ is, by definition, an element of order $p-1$.  Also worth noting:  your comment that "since $g^{p^n}\equiv 1$ then the order of $g$ is $p^n$" is simply wrong.  All you could conclude is that the order of $g$ divided $p^n$.  Since $\gcd (p^n,p-1)=1$ that would then imply that the order of $g$ was $1$,

Comment: Also, by Fermat's little theorem, $g^{p^n}\equiv1\pmod p$ for prime $p$ and any integer $g$.

Comment: Ok what is an example of an element of prime power order? I am currently confused by this. I thought it was a number of the form $g^{p^n}\pmod{p}=1$ however now it seems this is wrong

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: How about $0^{p^n}\equiv 0\pmod{p}$?

Comment: @unseen_rider : $2$ has order $2^2$, a prime power, modulo $5$, so is an example of an element of prime power order.  Of course, modulo $7$, a primitive root has order $6$, not a prime power, so no element of prime power order is a primitive root modulo $7$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $p$ is prime, then $g= g^p\pmod{p}$ for all $g\in\mathbb{Z}.$ This seems simple enough, but there is an important extension. Given $n>0$, define $r(g)$ such that $\;r(g)= g^{p^{n-1}}\pmod{p^n}.$ Then if $g\ne 0\pmod{p},\; r(g)\;$ is a $(p\!-\!1)$th root of unity. This is because the order of the multiplicative group $\!\pmod{p^n}$ is $p^{n-1}(p-1)$ and so  $g^{p^{n-1}(p-1)}=1\pmod{p^n}$ implies $r(g)^{p-1}= 1\pmod{p^n}.$ Therefore, $\;g^{p^n}=r(g)\pmod{p^n},\;$ but $\;r(g)\;$ has $\;p-1\;$ values including $1$.

Now if $g_1$ is a primitive  $(p\!-\!1)$th root of unity, then ${g_1}^k$ for all $0\le k<p\!-\!1\;$ are all the $(p\!-\!1)$th roots of unity.

Notice that if  $g\ne 0\pmod{p},$ then $\;r(g) = 1\pmod{p}$ by Fermat's little theorem, but for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ $(pk)^{p^n}=0\pmod{p}$.

Notice that in a [finite field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field) with $p^n$ elements that $g^{p^n}=g$ for all $g,\;$ but the multiplicative group order here is $p^n-1,$ implying that if $g\ne 0,$ then $\;g^{p^n-1}=1.$